Why does this proof work: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^ \infty \left(\frac{1}{4n-1} - \frac{1}{4n}\right)= \frac{\ln(64)- \pi}{8}$?
$$f(x):= \sum_{n=1}^ \infty \left(\frac{x^{4n-1}}{4n-1} - \frac{x^{4n}}{4n}\right)$$
$$f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^ \infty ( x^{4n-2}- x^{4n-1})= \frac{x^2}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}$$
$$\int_0 ^1 \frac{x^2}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}= \frac{\ln(64)- \pi}{8} $$
This proof is not correct because $f_N(x) := \sum\limits_{n=1}^ \infty \left(\frac{x^{4n-1}}{4n-1} - \frac{x^{4n}}{4n}\right) $  and $f_N'(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^ N( x^{4n-2}- x^{4n-1})= x^{4}\left(\frac{1-x}{x^2}  \right)\frac{x^{4N+4}-1 }{x^4-1}$ doesn't converge uniformly so the the derivative and the sum couldn't be interchanged but the answer is correct. Is it a coincidence ? Is there is other condition to interchange sum and  derivative that don't require uniform convergence? Is there is a way to justify this ? Any other conditions?
I am pretty sure I can generate an infinite cases where this interchange work from this example by changing the '4' to any other  integer greater than 1. So why does this work ?

A theorem is a sufficient but not necessary condition.

@zkutch My question is: Is there is a way to justify this ? Any other conditions?

Could you include a proof that the sum does not converge uniformly?

@user $x^{4N+4}-1 $ doesn't converge  uniformly to $-1$ all the other variables don't depend on $N$.

I don't quite understand: if you mean it does not converge uniformly at the end of the interval - it does not matter.

@user Can you explain why ?

The idea is already given in the answer.

Well, actually it does converge uniformly. To evaluate a derivative at a point $0<x<1$, you only need space nearby to $x$. So, you could work on $[0,x+\frac{1-x}{2}]$ with the right hand limit strictly below $1$. And now there is no issue with $x^k$, it uniformly converges to zero and you can evaluate $f'$ in this way. And now you know $f'$ on $(0,1)$, you can integrate on every $(\delta,1-\delta)$ and take limits and get your answer, using obvious continuity of $f$ at zero. A little bit of care is needed to get $\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=f(1)$ though, but Abel's theorem saves the day.
What we have here is local uniform convergence which is good enough. You can sometimes use the magic of dominated/monotone convergence theorem to get away with less.

For integrating a typical geometric series you can always do a direct analysis rather than using uniform convergence and Abel's theorem.
Thus we can observe that $$\sum_{k=1}^n(t^{4k-2}-t^{4k-1})=\frac{t^2-t^3}{1-t^4}-(t^2-t^3)\cdot\frac{t^{4n}}{1-t^4}$$ and then we can integrate term by term to get $$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{x^{4k-1}}{4k-1}-\frac{x^{4k}}{4k}\right)=\int_0^x\frac{t^2}{(1+t)(1+t^2)}\,dt-R_n(x)$$ where $$R_n(x) =\int_0^x\frac{t^{4n+2}}{(1+t)(1+t^2)}\,dt$$ The limiting behavior of remainder term $R_n(x) $ can now be analyzed  for $|x|\leq 1$. In particular for $x=1$ we have $$0<R_n(1)<\int_0^1 t^{4n+2}\,dt=\frac{1}{4n+3}$$ and thus on taking limits as $n\to\infty$ we get $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac {1}{4k-1}-\frac{1}{4k}\right) =\int_0^1\frac{t^2}{(1+t)(1+t^2)}\,dt$$

I think the aim of the question was to reveal necessary conditions to interchange differentiation and summation.

@user: I perhaps misinterpreted "is there any way to justify this" in the question.

Perhaps it is me who misunderstood the question.
